# Loop through an array in PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

Is there a way to refer to a value of an array inside of an aray?

For example.

I have the following php code to loop through an array listed below.  Can I easily get the `[product_name] => DIESEL #2` data without another for loop?  If I know the data will always come this way?  Something like $`fuel = $value['transaction_id'.'product'.'product_name']`?

```
foreach ($result['data'] as $key => $value) {
    $id =  $value['id'];
    $transactionId =  "FC".$value['transaction_id'];
    $transactionDateTime = $value['created_utc'];
    echo $id." - ".$transactionDateTime." - ".$transactionId." </br>";


}



(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5750574
                    [label] => 
                    [self] => https://api.fuelcloud.com/rest/v1.0/transaction/5750574
                    [transaction_id] => 0025621e-3270-c0e2-8d2a-6425ed834f9d
                    [transaction_type] => 1
                    [tank_id] => 23744
                    [start_date] => 2019-12-19T00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-12-19T23:59:59Z
                    [site_id] => 23743
                    [product_id] => 409
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 409
                            [product_name] => DIESEL #2
                            [product_category] => diesel
                        )
```

Comment: $fuel = $value['product']['product_name']; is it what you are loooking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to reference array entries, it seems, like `$value['id']`. `$value['product']` is another array, and `$value['product']['product_name']` is the value of the `product_name` key from that array.

Comment: I feel so stupid.  TY.  I don't code in PHP full time.  Looks like a simple syntax issue on my part.